# Difference between debug and build run on CLion

Tags: c

I just started programming and I'm struggling a bit with this one piece of code I wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FACE 6

enum Status {WON, LOST, CONTINUE};
int RollDice (void);

int main() {
    enum Status gameStatus;

    int sum = RollDice();
    int myPoint;

    switch (sum){

        case 7:
        case 11:
            gameStatus = WON;
            break;

        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 12:
            gameStatus = LOST;
            break;

        default:
            gameStatus = CONTINUE;
            myPoint = sum;
            break;
    }


    while (gameStatus == CONTINUE){
        sum = RollDice();

        if (sum == myPoint)
            gameStatus = WON;
        else if (sum == 7)
            gameStatus = LOST;

    }

    printf ("\n%s", (gameStatus==WON)? "WON":"LOST");

    return 0;
}

int RollDice (void) {
    int die[2];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        die[j] = 1 + rand() % FACE;

    printf ("\n\nRolled %d and %d", die[0],die[1]);

    return die[0]+die[1];
}
```

Building and Running it on CLion always end up giving something like:

```
Rolled 6 and 4

Rolled 6 and 4
WON
Process finished with exit code 0
```

or

```
Rolled 3 and 3

Rolled 3 and 3
WON
Process finished with exit code 0
```

which is not wrong per se, but I do not expect to ALWAYS have such a result

On the other hand, when I try to debug it everything is fine and the program behaves as expected up to the final printf, which is not executed and exit code 0 is therefore never attained, it just redirects me to some disassembly file I don't know about.

On XCode (I use a mac) I don't have any such problem, neither when running nor debagging.
Someone can please help me understand?

thanks a lot

Comment: Call `srand(time(NULL));` only once (at the very beginning)

Comment: On most common systems the `time` function returns the time since a specified starting point *in seconds*. That means if you call `time(NULL)` twice within the same second, it will return the same value. Now think about what happens if you reset the random-number generator with the same starting values twice.

Comment: Thanks so much. Could someone explain me why prior to the correction you suggested, Xcode runs the program differently from CLion, which by the way is set to use Xcode compiler?